# CSS и генерируемая таблица

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript, css

Подскажите, где у меня пробел в знаниях и помогите решить решить задачу пожалуйста.
Есть таблица, thead описан в шаблоне. Но tbody формируется с помощью php тут же в шаблоне скриптом. Выглядит это так:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" class="sortable" id="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<thead>
  <tr>                
     <th>Заголовки</th>
     <th>...</th>    
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <div id="refresh"></div>
 </tbody> 
</table>
```

Вставляю в div функцию php с помощью javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#refresh').load('функция php');
});
```

Сама php функция выглядит так:

```
  <?php
         $ndata=$data->fetch_all();
         foreach ($ndata as $key){
             echo "<tr>";
             foreach ($key as $n){
                 echo "<td>";
                 echo $n;
                 echo "</td>";                
             }
             echo "</tr>";
         }
  ?>
```

И когда срабатывает ввод данных в таблицe, они у меня оказываются над шапкой таблицы и оказываются неотформатированными с помощью css.
Подскажите как тут выйти из ситуации? Мне данные нужно подгружать в таблицу из БД сразу как только там появилась новая запись, не перегружая страницу. Новая запись появляется нажатием кнопки "добавить".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

строки таблицы надо добавлять в tbody, а не в div. Так попробуйте сделать:

```
...
<tbody id="refresh"></tbody>
...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. Но перестал теперь работать плагин jquery.dataTables для обработки таблицы. Не видит данные в таблице.

Comment: ну так может он не видит из-за того, что плагин пытается их увидеть сразу, а вы их загружаете аяксом. у dataTables есть свой механизм загрузки данных аяксом, правда там не html, а json передается. [Вот пример](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html) загрузки данных, думаю нужно идти этим путем.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, я как раз недавно уже нашел сам.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял вы используете JQuery
Попробуйте вот так:

$(newRowContent).appendTo($("#refresh"));

либо так

$("#refresh tbody").append(newRowContent);

где newRowContent это код вашей таблицы.

Comment: Не работает, так же стили не срабатывают:(